# How to cancel Postgresql transaction and do nothing?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, transactions

I am using the following query to insert data to PostgreSQL tables user and password.

```
BEGIN; 
INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_username, user_name, user_surname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?); 
INSERT INTO passwords (user_id, user_password) VALUES (?, ?); 
COMMIT;
```

I would like to cancel the transaction in case of user_id or user_username conflict. I know `ON CONFLICT (user_id, user_username) DO NOTHING` may help in this case but I am afraid it won't actually cancel the insertion to the password table.

How can I make it so in a case of conflict all of the transaction will be cancelled?

Comment: Avoid the `on conflict` clause altogether. Both `insert` statements are contained in the same transaction, if a unique constraint violation occurs on either one then *both* are rolled back. You should add the [exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)  phase to you code and log the exception.

Comment: Cancel when? Don't COMMIT, instead ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction block already achieves your goal: if any of the statements in the transaction causes an error (because of a unique key violation), the whole transaction will be undone and rolled back.

Answer (score -1):

"ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" means that when a conflict occurs while inserting a row into a table, the row will not be inserted. "ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE" means that when conflict occurs while inserting a row into the table, the existing row that conflicts with the new row will be updated with the newer values.

you can refer to [ON CONFLICT docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

Comment: This ain’t valid SQL syntax, could you fix the code or remove it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).